# Populating Umbraco Contour forms from using cookie data

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco-contour

We're currently using Umbraco version 7.1.4 assembly: 1.0.5261.28127 with Contour version 3.0.26

I'm trying to populate a contour form with information pulled from a database, but dependent on a user cookie (the cookie hold the primary key for the record in the database).

To implement this I'm looking at writing a custom field type (well a bunch of them, one for each data field) which examines the cookie makes the db request and then populates the textbox with the value (users name/address/etc).

I've managed to add custom setting to a control and have it display the value that's populated at design time, but I can't seem to amend that value at run time.

I'm happy to post the code if relevant, but my question is. Am I barking up the wrong tree? is this the best way to handle this or would it even work?

Any pointers would be most welcome

Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks Tim,
   I've now managed to break it in such a way it's not even rendering the controls (the debug message is saying the SVT value doesn't exist).
This just (or should) just populate the form with the current date/time just to get something working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Custom.FieldType
{
    public class CustomTextfield : Umbraco.Forms.Core.FieldType
    {
        public CustomTextfield()
        {
            //Provider 
            this.Id = new Guid("b994bc8b-2c65-461d-bfba-43c4b3bd2915");
            this.Name = "Custom Textfield";
            this.Description = "Renders a html input fieldKey"; //FieldType 
            this.Icon = "textfield.png";
            this.SVT = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        public System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox tb;
        public List<Object> _value;

        [Umbraco.Forms.Core.Attributes.Setting("SVT", description = "the SVT")]
        public string SVT { get; set; }

        public override WebControl Editor
        {
            get
            {
                tb.TextMode = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                tb.CssClass = "text gaudete";


                if (_value.Count > 0)
                    tb.Text = _value[0].ToString();

                SVT = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                tb.Text = tb.Text + SVT;

                return tb;
            }
            set { base.Editor = value; }
        }

        public override List<Object> Values
        {
            get
            {
                if (tb.Text != "")
                {
                    _value.Clear();
                    _value.Add(tb.Text);
                }
                return _value;
            }
            set { _value = value; }
        }

        public override string RenderPreview()
        {
            return
                "<input type=\"text\" id=\"text-content\" class=\"text\" maxlength=\"500\" value=\"" + this.SVT + "\" />";
        }

        public override string RenderPreviewWithPrevalues(List<object> prevalues)
        {
            return RenderPreview();
        }

        public override bool SupportsRegex
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

    }
}
```

And the view is

```
@model Umbraco.Forms.Mvc.Models.FieldViewModel
@{
    var widthSetting = Model.AdditionalSettings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key.Equals("Width"));
    string width = (widthSetting == null) ? null : widthSetting.Value;
    var textSetting = Model.AdditionalSettings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key.Equals("SVT"));
    string widthTXT = (textSetting == null) ? null : textSetting.Value;
}
<input type="text" name="@Model.Name" id="@Model.Id" class="text"  maxlength="500"  

        value="@{if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(widthTXT)){<text>@(SVT)</text>}}"

    @{if(Model.Mandatory || Model.Validate){<text>data-val="true"</text>}}
    @{if (Model.Mandatory) {<text> data-val-required="@Model.RequiredErrorMessage"</text>}}
    @{if (Model.Validate) {<text> data-val-regex="@Model.InvalidErrorMessage" data-regex="@Model.Regex"</text>}}
/>
```

The code is mostly cobbled together from online tutorials which is why the naming is abysmal but if I can get something to populate the text box on the clients side then I can start the process of refactoring (well scrapping this demo version and writing a real version)

Thanks.

**EDIT2**

I was able to fix the error stopping the view loading thanks to the pointer from Tim, the new view looks as follows

```
@model Umbraco.Forms.Mvc.Models.FieldViewModel
@{
    var textSetting = Model.AdditionalSettings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key.Equals("SVT"));
    string widthTXT = (textSetting == null) ? null : textSetting.Value;
}
<input type="text" name="@Model.Name" id="@Model.Id" class="text"  maxlength="500"  

        value="@{if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(widthTXT)){<text>@(widthTXT)</text>}else{<text>Unknown</text>}}"

    @{if(Model.Mandatory || Model.Validate){<text>data-val="true"</text>}}
    @{if (Model.Mandatory) {<text> data-val-required="@Model.RequiredErrorMessage"</text>}}
    @{if (Model.Validate) {<text> data-val-regex="@Model.InvalidErrorMessage" data-regex="@Model.Regex"</text>}}
/>
```

And just displays "Unknown" in the text box

thanks again.

Comment: Can you post your code? What you're trying to do should in theory be possible.

Comment: Thanks @Tim , It's helpful at least to know it should be possible :)

Comment: Try changing @(SVT) to @Model.SVT, does that work? It's currently erroring because you don't have a variable called SVT in the View.

Comment: Thanks @Tim (at)Model.SVT didn't help, but changing the it to widthTXT at least got it to load (this is the state I had it in the night before I posted the question :) )